# Soap Response parsing using cypress

Tags: soap, cypress

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPriceRespon`enter code here`se xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
    <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
  </m:GetPriceResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to read "Price" from above XML , how to read this price using cypress and store it to a variable ? could any one help me with the sample cypress code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DOMParser to make a queryable document,

```js
it('parses XML price', () => {
  
  const xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
     <soap:Body>
        <m:GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
           <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
        </m:GetPriceResponse>
     </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>`

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "application/xml");
  const price = +doc.querySelector("Price").textContent  // numeric value of text content

  cy.wrap(price)                   
    .as('price')                   // save for later
    .should('eq', 1.90)            // verify the value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
   <soap:Body>
      <m:GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
         <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
      </m:GetPriceResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

cy.wrap(Cypress.$(xml))
  .then((xml) => xml.filter('soap:Body').find('m:Price').text())
  .as('price')

cy.get('@price').then((price) => {
  //Access price here
})
```